# How to fix the git-upload-pack issue in Windows 10 Git

Tags: windows, git

There are several answer but I couldn't understand it to well.

I set up a bare repo in my desktop at C:/git/project1

my local ip is 192.168.0.2

when I tried to clone project1 in my laptop: Roi@192.168.0.2

git-upload-pack not recognized pops up.

is there a step-by-step procedure to fix this?

I'm new to git generally so I have little idea of the configs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ssh Roi@192.168.0.2` works (from your laptop, opening a shell session to your desktop), you need to make sure C:\path\to\Git\bin is in the *system* PATH of your desktop.

An alternative would be to defined a shared folder on your desktop (above your repo folder), and access it through `\\192.168.0.2\shareFolder\myrepo` from your laptop.
Then only Git on your laptop would be needed.